# Images not displaying in cart or mini cart

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, image

I seem to have lost my images from my cart page and also the mini cart at the top of the screen. When i go into a product and add to the cart then view the mini cart (hover over cart icon) then the image is displaying perfectly with the source

```
<img src="http://www.domain.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/50x50/4c28172cd5b58975125070293f464017/h/a/hat_101.gif" data-srcx2="http://www.domain.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/100x100/4c28172cd5b58975125070293f464017/h/a/hat_101.gif" width="50" height="50">
```

But then when i click on the cart to view the basket the image disappear and is replaced with the magento placeholder

```
<img src="http://www.domain.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/50x50/d2ef8acc7d0030db8e2cfcc27e37649a/images/catalog/product/placeholder/thumbnail.jpg" data-srcx2="http://www.domain.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/100x100/d2ef8acc7d0030db8e2cfcc27e37649a/images/catalog/product/placeholder/thumbnail.jpg" width="50" height="50" >
```

The line that calls the product image says,

```
<td class="td-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->getProductThumbnail()->resize($imgX,$imgY); ?>" data-srcX2="<?php echo $this->getProductThumbnail()->resize($imgX*2,$imgY*2); ?>" width="<?php echo $imgX;?>" height="<?php echo $imgY;?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getProductName()) ?>" /></td>
```

which if i am correct should get the  product image thumbnail, resize it and display it?

Does anybody know what is going wrong here and why i am losing my image every time i refresh the page or click onto the cart page.

Thank you

Comment: Did you flushed the cache including the image cache?

Comment: Yea i flushed the image cache, if that the problem have can i get it back? or get it to not use a cached image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the catalog image helper to get any type of image.

```
$_product = $_item->getProduct();
echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(50,50);
```

Comment: This answer will work which is why i accepted it but i found out that the reason the images wasn't appearing was because when i imported a CSV file for my products it mucked up my database. But cheers for the response anyway